# DiscordJS online members count

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am making my discord Admin bot (only for my server) and I am trying to do online members counter. I tried this:

```js
client.guilds.cache.get(ids.serverID).members
  .filter(m => m.presence.status === 'online').size;
```

and it gave this error:

```
var online = client.guilds.cache.get(ids.serverID).members.filter(m => m.presence.status === 'online').size;
                                                           ^
TypeError: client.guilds.cache.get(...).members.filter is not a function
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/cyril/Documents/ALPHA-Admin/main.js:40:62)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at PresenceUpdateAction.handle (/home/cyril/Documents/ALPHA-Admin/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/PresenceUpdate.js:39:19)
    at Object.module.exports [as PRESENCE_UPDATE] (/home/cyril/Documents/ALPHA-Admin/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/PRESENCE_UPDATE.js:4:33)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/cyril/Documents/ALPHA-Admin/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/cyril/Documents/ALPHA-Admin/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/cyril/Documents/ALPHA-Admin/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/cyril/Documents/ALPHA-Admin/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/home/cyril/Documents/ALPHA-Admin/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:825:20)
```

Can anyone please help me out? Thank you.

Comment: Is `members` actually an array, or is it an object? Can you store the `members` into an array and then evaluate `Array.isArray(members)`?

Answer (score 2):

The [members](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=members) property is not an array, it is a [GuildMemberManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager) which doesn't have a `.filter()` method as part of its prototype. Try accessing the cache of your members list, which will return you a collection of the type `Collection<Snowflake, GuildMember>`, this type, unlike the GuildMemberManager, does have a [filter](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=filter) method, which will return a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) that you can then get the size of:

```
client.guilds.cache.get(ids.serverID).members.cache
  .filter(m => m.presence.status === 'online').size;
```

Comment: It think it's now working correctly, it shows false numbers ! my code: https://pastebin.com/9qAfy1sQ 
but it says 29 online and 6 offline, even that 32 online and 13 offline + 9 bots should ne 54 members
and it's saying these weird numbers 
why ?§

Comment: @nicoebd this is because it is measuring cached members, it will not be accurate since some members will not be cached. It is something we can not do anything to solve unfortunately. I would not do a member count command since it will never be accurate, focus on things that can be done to a high degree of accuracy.

Comment: @Proto so you are saying, that I can't do accurate online / offline stats, so member counter (just how many members is on server) can be accurate ? at least in normal range.... this server has now 54 members, after about 5 months of it exsistance and I think it would never grow above 1000, so in this range, is member counter accurate ?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: thank you very much